# Skype Interviews API

Tags: node.js, api, skype

I'm having a problem using the skype interviews API:

My problem is in implementation of the method GET,

This is the error in postman test: `Token error - err:1`

[image]

Details of HTTP request:

[image]

```
GET /api/interviews/w4474a56-8e4a-6870-7875-c64efb76bfa6 HTTP/1.1

Host: interviews.skype.com

Content-Type: application/json

Authorization: Bearer 8539e258-2778-8e39-a571-439e31f89973
```

My **INTERVIEW CODE**

`https://interviews.skype.com/scheduler?code=**w4474a56-8e4a-6870-7875-c64efb76bfa6**`

**The documentation, step 8, says:**

> If your application wants to leverage all the information that Skype Interviews can provide after an interview like the interviewer notes, feedback and the candidate's written code snapshots, then you can request the data with a simple HTTP request.
>
> To retrieve information such as "notes", "feedback" and "code snapshots", we just need to issue a HTTP GET request to https://interviews.skype.com/api/interviews/YOUR_INTERVIEW_CODE.
>
> note: for the GET request please omit the sub property in the JWT token.
>
> Here's an example request to retrieve the information.
>
> Request
>
> ```
> GET /api/interviews/YOUR_INTERVIEW_CODE HTTP/1.1
> ```
>
> Host: interviews.skype.com
>
> Authorization: Bearer
>
> Content-Type: application/json

Link: https://dev.skype.com/interviews#manage-jobs

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Leandro.

Comment: completing the above information, I did a test on node.js and the same error occurred:

Answer (score 0):

My friend, I had a similar issue with the token trying to consume a POST method. Your problem is the way you're generating the token...In my case I found out the example given to create the JWT token is mediocre. They say you have to use a Random GUID, but they never specify which encoding....

```
{
"jti": "d8661a14-4b7c-5fda-2227-9b055fcf5b10", // Random GUID
"iss": "YOUR_API_KEY",
"iat": 1519343714, // Current NumericDate
"sub": "44136fa355b3678a1146ad16f7e8649e94fb4fc21fe77e8310c060f61caaff8a", // SHA256 
hash request body
"exp": 1519343724 // Current NumericDate + 10 seconds
}
```

My solution was run this code inside a .js file, installing first:

`npm install --save guid sha256 jsonwebtoken node-fetch`

And then printing the Guid with the correct encoding, to use later to generate the token.

Test.js:

```
const Guid = require('guid');
const sha256 = require('sha256');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
function generateToken(content) {
jwt.sign({
jti: Guid.raw(),
iss: '7a80954b-d782-72d4-ec7f-e76c36c58593',
sub: sha256(content),
exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 10
}, '10620340-0f64-1f6e-ad25-49b53929bf9e')
console.log(Guid.raw());
}
generateToken(JSON.stringify({}));
```